# Routing issues when serving Angular 5 SPA out of a Lumen 5.2 controller endpoint

Tags: php, angular, laravel, nginx, lumen

I am trying to serve an Angular SPA out of a single routed Lumen endpoint. The initial boot of the Angular application works when navigating directly to the endpoint works, loading any child route of the Angular SPA is not working

#### # index.twig

```
class CoreSpaController extends AbstractTemplateController
{
    public function index()
    {
        return $this->renderView('@spa/index.twig');
    }
}
```

#### # routes.php

```
$app->group([
    'prefix' => 'app',
], function (Application $app) {
    $app->get('/', ['as' => 'app.home', 'uses' => 'Spa\\SpaController@index']);

    $app->get('*', function() {
        return 'foo';
    });
});
```

The Lumen application is served through a proxy pass

#### # nginx.conf

```
location ~ (/app) {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host:$server_port;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_pass http://lumenDockerRunningContainer;
  }
```

`/app/` loads fine

`/app/foo` which is a properly routed Angular child throws a Lumen `NotFoundHttpException`.

The problem is not in the Angular SPA, as when it is served through an index.html, the application routes as expected.

Any help/suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try registering a route to pass all requests to `SpaController@index`

Comment: @OluwafemiSule Isn't that what the `$app->get('*', function() { return 'hi'; });` route would accomplish?

Comment: No, currently that returns 'hi'. If the idea is to have SpaController@index serve as the front controller, you'll need to pass all request through it.

Comment: @OluwafemiSule The problem is that it does not return 'hi', if it did I would redirect to the `route('app.home');`

Answer (score 0):

Try this out.

```
$app->get('/{any:.*}', ['as' => 'globalRoute', 'uses' => 'Spa\\SpaController@index']);
```